# Safe Operator for Duck Typing in Groovy/GSP

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I'm new to Grails development, and I'm wondering what the standard way of handling this problem is:

In a GSP, I'm iterating over a list of domain objects, many, but not all of which have a getX() method.  I want to a tag that looks like this:

```
<g:each in="${myObjects}>
  ${it.x}
</g:each>
```

However, since some of my object don't have a getX method, I am getting a 'No such property' exception.  I would like it if there was some sort of operator like the 'safe operator' that prevents NPEs. Is there good way of handling this without doing an 'instanceof'?

Comment: Be aware that if your objects have a `getX` method, then accessing with the property syntax should be `it.x` (notice the lowercase on the x). If that was the problem then my answer below doesn't make any sense =P

Comment: Thanks. I made the change from it.X to it.x in the code example above so not to confuse other readers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid Groovy's operators wont help you here. The [safe navigation operator (`?.`)](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SafeNavigationOperator) would help you if the reference on which you want to call a method could be null; and the [Elvis operator (`?:`)](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-ElvisOperator) would help you if your `x` property would be a property of all the objects, except that for some of them it might be null (something like `it.x ?: 'no x here'`).

In this case --i assume you are working with a collection of objects of different classes, some of them which do not have an `x` property-- you may ask the object if it has the property `x` (notice that if the object implements a method called `getX`, then `it.hasProperty('x')` will be true):

```
<g:each in="${myObjects}>
  ${it.hasProperty('x') ? it.x : 'no x here'}
</g:each>
```

Replace the `'no x here'` bit with whatever your fallback value might be. Also, you might consider using the [`<g:if>`](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Tags/if.html)/[`<g:else>`](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Tags/else.html) tags instead of the ternary operator if the logic for both options is more complicated than a simple expression :)